# How do I take values from 3 fields (Month, Day, Year) and have all three of these fields inserted as a single field (MySQL)?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've created an HTML form and its corresponding insert.php code.  The question I have is this:

1) Does PHP read the ID or NAME field (HTML) when the user presses submit on an HTML form?
2) How do I use PHP to combine fields so that it is inserted into a MySQL Database in a single column/field?   (I'm trying to be more specific;  last few Questions of mine were flagged on Stack, so I'm -trying- to adhere to the community standard)

```
<label class="description" for="element_23">Date of Birth </label>
    <span>
        <input id="element_23_1" name="applicants.DOB_month" class="element text" size="2" maxlength="2" value="" type="text"> /
        <label for="element_23_1">MM</label>
    </span>
    <span>
        <input id="element_23_2" name="applicants.DOB_day" class="element text" size="2" maxlength="2" value="" type="text"> /
        <label for="element_23_2">DD</label>
    </span>
    <span>
        <input id="element_23_3" name="applicants.DOB_year" class="element text" size="4" maxlength="4" value="" type="text">
        <label for="element_23_3">YYYY</label>
    </span>
```

--MySQL--

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO applicants (fname, lname, address, city, state, zip, country, phone, school, DOB, age, amount_requested) VALUES ('$applicants_fname', '$applicants_lname', '$applicants_address','$applicants_city','$applicants_state','$applicants_zip','$applicants_country','$applicants_phone','$applicants_school','$DOB','$age', '$applicants_amount_requested')";
```

Answer (score 1):

To create 1 field in DB from 3 fields with data from your form you can get all this 3 fields (from `$_POST` оr `$_GET` array (this param must be in `<form>s action attribute`)):

```
$value = $_POST['field1_name'].'/'.$_POST['field2_name'].' /'.$_POST['field3_name'];
```

and then insert it into DB.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a new variable and concatenate the ones you want to be entered in the db, then use that variable as the final product.

I.e.: and assuming a POST form method, since you did not specify that in your question.

```
$year = $_POST['applicants.DOB_year'];
$month = $_POST['applicants.DOB_month'];
$day = $_POST['applicants.DOB_day'];

$DOB = $year . "-" . $month . "-" . $day;

$sql = "INSERT INTO applicants 
        (fname, lname, address, city, state, zip, country, phone, school, DOB, age, amount_requested) 
        VALUES ('$applicants_fname', '$applicants_lname', '$applicants_address','$applicants_city',
        '$applicants_state','$applicants_zip','$applicants_country','$applicants_phone','$applicants_school',
        '$DOB','$age', '$applicants_amount_requested')";
```

You'll also want to set your column as a DATE type since MySQL stores that as YYYY-MM-DD.

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

The reason being that it will be easier to query later. You will have a harder time if your column is set to VARCHAR and would have to result in using more functions/resources than what is required.

- Use MySQL's built-in DATE functions.

The above will render something like 1995-12-22

From the manual:

> The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.

You should also use a prepared statement, since your code may be prone to an SQL injection. It is unknown if you are escaping your data.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

> *"1) Does PHP read the ID or NAME field (HTML) when the user presses submit on an HTML form?"*

If you're using pure PHP, then it relies on the "name" attribute.

- Consult http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

JS/Ajax however, does support the ID attribute though.

- Consult http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-bootstrap-contact-form-using-php-and-ajax--cms-23068

Comment: @Cryptik You should mark one of the answers given as solved, since your question is still considered open and some may think that the question isn't solved and may want to post more answers.

Answer (score 0):

it depends of your column type but if this is a string,
you can use MySQL CONCAT

```
INSERT INTO `table`(`field`) VALUES (CONCAT('val1', '/', 'val2', '/', 'val3'));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. on form submit, the request string is created from the `name` fields, not the `id`. Thus the request is `name1=value1&name2=value2` ....
2. You have to create the valid value to insert in the right field. You can use php and concatenate values `$values = $_POST['name1'] . 'delimiter' . $_POST['name2']` or you can use the SQL CONCAT function.